# Xml document GetElementsByTagName

Tags: xml, f#, getelementsbytagname

Is there an `F#` equivalent for the following syntax?

```ml
document.getElementsByTagName()[0]
```

I am trying to pull back only one record for a tag with multiple elements and someone said it was possible if I use this method.

Answer (score 3):

The method call and indexed access work the same way in F#, though the syntax for [indexed properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx) in F# has an additional dot:

```ml
document.GetElementsByTagName("mytag").[0]
```

If you need a certain path to the element, the XPath version is nicer:

```ml
document.SelectNodes("/path/mytag").[0]
```